# How can I send mail using php mail function and have anchor tag work for my email template

Tags: gmail, phpmailer, email-formats

I have tried sending a test mail using below mail template with php mail function but when this email came to a gmail inbox output was not the expected. Below are the snippets.

**mail template:**

Hi <name>,

Here is the subject of your order: <subject text with link to order>

Thanks,

**What I received:**

Hi Yen,

Here is the subject of your order: <a href="https://www.someurl.com/link/orderid">subject text with link to order</a>

Thanks,

**Here is what I expected:**

Hi Yen,

Here is the subject of your order: [subject text with link to order](https://www.someurl.com/link/orderid)

Thanks,

Comment: You're only describing the symptom - we need to see the code. You're probably missing appropriate MIME structure and content-type headers.

Comment: Yes you are right  and I did incorporated that to fix the problem.

Comment: Glad that works - but I suggest you delete this question as it's unlikely to be of help to anyone else.